# How do we use limits to prove differentiability of a complex function and then prove the limit unique within the neighborhood of the point?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, analyticity

With complex functions, there are several paths that can be taken to approach a point $z_0$. We usually take the limit
$$
f(z)' = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(z_0+z) - f(z_0)}{z}
$$
If I take an example, $w = z^3$,

$$
w' = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(z_0+z) - f(z_0)}{z} 
$$

$= \lim_{z \to 0}  \frac{(x+iy+z)^3 - (x+iy)^3}{z}$

And using Newton's binomial theorem,

$$
w' = 3(x+iy)^2 = 3z^2
$$

This is the correct derivative of z^3 but I don't exactly understand the mechanics at play here because if we check w' for uniqueness,

$\lim_{x \to 0} \lim_{y \to 1}$   will give us $w' = -3$ while $\lim_{x \to 1} \lim_{y \to 0}$ will give us $w' = 3$.

These are two distinct values, making the limit not unique, hence not analytic. But if the limit I used to obtain w' used z as it's variable, can I test the derivative with x and y? Or only with z?

Comment: One is $f'(i)$, the other $f'(1)$. The derivative isn't a constant function in this case.

Comment: @DanielFischer Then how exactly do you check if the derivative is unique? It has to have the same value in all the ways we approach $z_0$

Comment: But you're doing something else. You take the limit of the derivative at two distinct points. What you should do is look at $$\frac{f(z_0 + z) - f(z_0)}{z} = \frac{3z_0^2z + 3z_0z^2 + z^3}{z} = 3z_0^2 + 3z_0z + z^2$$ and show that this tends to $3z_0^2$ as $z \to 0$. You can assume $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant 1$, then the difference is bounded by $(3\lvert z_0\rvert + 1)\cdot \lvert z\rvert$.

Comment: Your notation is fishy. Your complex variable is $z$, and you take the derivative of some $f$ at a fixed point $z_0=x_0+iy_0$. You should then denote the "increment vectors" attached at $z_0$ by $h$, and not by$z$. E.g., you have the function $w(z):=z^3$ and have computed $w'(z_0)=3z_0^2=3(x_0+iy_0)^2$. Your "check for uniqueness" makes no sense.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, that's exactly what I've done save for representing complex variables in the form x + iy; my question is, once you get that limit tending to 3$z_0^2$, how can we then check the uniqueness of the derivative to ensure the function is analytical?

Comment: What do you mean with checking uniqueness? Once you have shown the limit exists, you're done.

Comment: @DanielFischer Well let P be the fixed point and Q be any point in it's neighborhood, Q can approach P along any straight or curved path and may tend to zero in any manner, so the value of the derivative may be different for different approaches right? So the value has to be the same for every single approach, which is what I mean by the derivative being "unique" (as said in my college textbook)

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Sorry, my bad. I meant to use z and delta z but I didn't know how to format it, so I used $z_0$ and z instead